# Web games are being played less by the year, is this only on PC, or also on Mobile?

Tags: game-industry

I just came from reading the [NewZoo](https://newzoo.com) 2016 global game market report. The last time I read it, I noticed that the web game's segment was less than the years before (it was 5% in 2016, 6% in 2015, 9% in 2014, and 10% in 2013)

[image: Newzoo global games market report]
[image: Newzoo global games market report]

But these are all for users who accessed games using their PCs not mobile phones. And if you've been following the current trends of game portal websites, you'll notice that they are moving to mobile. Both [Kongregate](https://www.kongregate.com) and [Miniclip](https://www.miniclip.com), two very big gaming portals, have started publishing games on the two major app stores. They (and the larger part of web game publishers) will usually reject any HTML game doesn't support mobile. So they are definitely aware of this trend.

So now my questions is: what are the stats when it comes to web games on mobile?
 Does anyone know any resource that has stats on this?

Comment: The first image doesn't show an actual decrease, the 10% of 75 billion is less than the 9% of 102 billion.

Comment: It may be difficult to get good answers to this question here. Either this research has already been done and published somewhere, in which case the answer is just a link you could find through searching, or it hasn't been researched / is proprietary data, in which case we'd have no evidence we could share. Both cases would quickly go out of date as time passes and the best  available data changes. If you just want help searching for this data, putting out a call to GameDev Twitter or similar might be a faster way to gather input.

Comment: @Bálint, but it still means that less people (in comparison to the greater population) want to play web games, either that or the numbers for web games are staying the same and gamers in other sectors are growing increasing.

Comment: @DMGregory I'm sure there must be someone who run by some data on the mobile traffic for these sites. There has to be. I'm beginning to think I might just start hitting some of the forums of the big sites like Kongregate/Miniclip (Don't know about miniclip's forum though)

Comment: Kongregate has a history of being pretty forthcoming with data that might help developers on their platform — have you tried asking them directly?

Comment: @DMGregory on it. I actually read one of their reports on Unity Web player, and it had a good amount of data. I'll send an email.

Comment: When Kongregate publishes a game on the app store, wouldn't that classify as a smartphone/tablet game rather than a web game?

Comment: @immibis Yes it would, but I'm talking about the current crop of [HTML5 games on their site](http://blog.kongregate.com/html5-is-here/) that have mobile support or get mobile phone traffic. They only sponsor HTML5 games that have mobile support. I highly doubt there are any exceptions.